# Check integrity of .tar.gz backup

Tags: backup, tar

If you backup your system and create a .tar.gz with thousands of files and directories, how do you easily check its integrity? (ie without having to decompress).

It's good to keep backups, but it's even better to actually make sure your backups will work when the time comes... and I'd like to know an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the test suggested by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams you might also want to create separate checksum files for your tarballs. While it doesn't catch tarballs which got corrupted during their initial creation, it will allow you to later verify that the files are still in their original state, and that they haven't gotten corrupted by disk or file system problems.

Assuming the backup backup_20110724.tar.gz is created, you might also want to have something along the following command being run:

```
sha256sum backup_20110724.tar.gz > backup_20110724.tar.gz.sha256
```

It will then create a file containing something like this:

```
6d5fc8993d88739247ab76c01ddf3164e585b3ed02a63362cd209d2ba463eda5  backup_20110724.tar.gz
```

You can then later verify the integrity doing something along these lines:

```
sha256sum -c backup_20110724.tar.gz.sha256
```

Answer (score 4):

Tarballs don't have any way of checking their integrity other than decompressing, since they don't actually store checksums anywhere. Fortunately, listing the contents is usually enough to check.

```
tar ztvf foo.tar.gz > /dev/null
```

If you do want checksums then you'll need to use another format, such as zip or 7-zip.

Comment: Thanks! Would the listing of the content be a secure way of checking that the file is valid? Or could it still be corrupt? And would ej 7Zip not be a superior way to backup, then?

Comment: The decompression will fail if the file is corrupt, although the files before the point of corruption would still be recoverable. 7-zip, while useful for some things, also has weaknesses that tar doesn't, such as a need to seek around in the file, which would be infeasible to perform on a tape backup.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the shawhatever at the same time you do the backup - it's a little safer, and usually faster too:

```
tar cjflS - /home | mtee 'cat > backup_20201207.tar.xz' 'sha256sum - > backup_20201207.sha256'
```

mtee is available from [https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/mtee.html](https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/%7Estrombrg/mtee.html)
Full disclosure: I wrote it.